# connecting to many distributed data bases in Grails 2.2.0

Tags: grails, grails-orm

In our project we are using Grails 2.2.0 with Groovy .

We have requirement One deployment multiple Database per country .Say if User belongs to US our Application will connect him to US data base when User belongs to  UK our application will connect to UK Data base .

Database are distributed data base on different server  .

I am doing investigation from long time , but still no clues how to do it in Grails 2.2.0  or Hibernate .

How to implement it in Grails 2.2.0  .